# ReCaptcha gives valid as a response even when one character is skipped

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I am using http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/verify.html, Reptcha gives valid as a response even one character is skipped.

Comment: For *one* of the words, and *sometimes*, yes. :)

Comment: As I know, you can write whatever you want for the most broken word of two. The idea, is that they use users inputs to recognize words after scanning books. So they can't check input for one of the words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore

> Each new word that cannot be read correctly by OCR is given to a user
>   in conjunction with another word for which the answer is already
>   known. The user is then asked to read both words. If they solve the
>   one for which the answer is known, the system assumes their answer is
>   correct for the new one. The system then gives the new image to a
>   number of other people to determine, with higher confidence, whether
>   the original answer was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be due to it allowing a small variance in errors as the words may not always be legible?

Answer (score -1):

[@Hasan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103904/recaptcha-gives-valid-as-a-response-even-when-one-character-is-skipped/7105251#7105251) is correct. All words displayed on ReCaptcha are not readable by OCR. Google's servers cannot correctly figure out what the answer is. So they put two words up. One that has received an overwhelmingly consistent number of answers from other ReCaptcha users, and one that is a new word. It doesn't tell you which is the "known" word, and which is the new one. If you get the "known" word correct, it will record what you submitted for the new word, and save that to it's database. If, later on, many more users give the same answer as you for your new word, then it will be transitioned from a new word to a "known" word.